# How to implement a retry functionality to Ant Design's Upload Component if uploading a file fails?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation, antd

I am using ReactJS, and working with uploading pictures. For this, I am using Ant Design's (version 4.6) upload component. In certain scenarios my upload fails and for those scenarios I want to add a retry functionality which would upload the picture again without having to choose it again, but I cannot figure out a way to do this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

This is my code block where I am using upload component:

```
<Form.Item name="my_photos"  colon={false}>
  {getFieldDecorator("my_photos", {
  valuePropName: "my_photos",
  getValueFromEvent: e => e && e.fileList,
  rules: [{ required: false, message: 'Upload at least two photos' }],
  })(
 <div className="d-flex">
    <Upload {...Constants.props} 
      multiple={true}  
      listType="text" 
      className="uploadbtn"
      progress= {{
      strokeColor: {
      '0%': '#108ee9',
    ' 100%': '#87d068',
       },
       strokeWidth: 3,
       format: percent => `${parseFloat(percent.toFixed(2))}%`,
       }}>                                      
         <div>Browse</div>                                                            
    </Upload>
</div>
)}
</Form.Item>
```

This is another named as Constants in my project, which contains my custom request for upload:

```
export const props = {
    customRequest({
      action,
      data,
      file,
      filename,
      headers,
      onError,
      onProgress,
      onSuccess,
      withCredentials
    }) {
      var jwt_token = localStorage.getItem(<Token_Name>);
      AWS.config.update({
          region: <Region Name>,
          credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
              IdentityPoolId: <PoolID>,
              Logins: { 
                  <Login>: jwt_token,
              }
          })
      });
  
      const S3Obj = new AWS.S3();
   
  
      const objectParameters = {
          Bucket: "my_bucket",
          Key: "my_bucket_files" + "/" + file.uid + "/" + file.name,
          ACL: 'public-read',
          Body: file,
          ContentType: file.type
      };
  
      S3Obj.putObject(objectParameters)
        .on("httpUploadProgress", function({ loaded, total }) {
          onProgress(
            {
              percent: Math.round((loaded / total) * 100)
            },
            file
          );
        })
        .send(function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
            onError();
            message.error('Upload Failed. Try Again.');
            console.log(err.code);
            console.log(err.message);
          } else {
            onSuccess(data.response, file);
            message.success('Upload Successful!');
          }
        });
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add another Button to handle retry, and view it on code change.

See https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-dawn-pbktg?file=/index.js

In the code:

- upload on file selection
- show file list
- show retry button on failed files
- upload on retry.

What needs to be added by you:

- upload only failed files on retry
- handle all other cases
- update the list to show files that their status fixed by retrying.

Code:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Upload, message, Button } from "antd";
import { UploadOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
import reqwest from "reqwest";

function App() {
  const [fileList, setFileList] = useState([]);
  const [hasError, setHasError] = useState(false);
  const [uploading, setUploading] = useState(false);
  const props = {
    name: "file",
    action: "https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76",
    headers: {
      authorization: "authorization-text"
    },
    onChange(info) {
      if (info.file.status !== "uploading") {
        console.log(info.file, info.fileList);
      }
      if (info.file.status === "done") {
        message.success(`${info.file.name} file uploaded successfully`);
        setHasError(false);
        setFileList([]);
      } else if (info.file.status === "error") {
        message.error(`${info.file.name} file upload failed.`);
        setHasError(true);
        setFileList([...fileList, info.file]);
      }
    }
  };
  const handleRetry = () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    const files = fileList.filter((file) => file.status === "error");
    files.forEach((file) => {
      formData.append("files[]", file);
    });

    setUploading(true);

    // You can use any AJAX library you like
    reqwest({
      url: "https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76",
      method: "post",
      processData: false,
      data: formData,
      success: () => {
        setUploading(false);
        setHasError(false);
        setFileList([]);

        message.success("upload successfully.");
      },
      error: () => {
        setUploading(false);
        setHasError(true);
        setFileList([...fileList]);
        message.error("upload failed.");
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Upload {...props}>
        <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Click to Upload</Button>
      </Upload>

      {hasError && (
        <Button
          type="primary"
          onClick={handleRetry}
          disabled={fileList.length === 0}
          loading={uploading}
          style={{ marginTop: 16 }}
        >
          {uploading ? "Uploading" : "Retry"}
        </Button>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: what if there is a customRequest?